# Preventing navigation in Ionic App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to prevent navigation and show a popup in a controller.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  if(someConditionMet) {
    event.preventDefault();
    showPopup();
  }
}
```

This is working like a charm anything other than tab navigation. It cannot prevent navigation properly and navigates to a tab then shows popup. Another problem kicks in here because of the scope change popup fails to load properly and raises exception. I only see a blank popup with no way to exit after this.

Edit - Plunker demo http://plnkr.co/edit/r8MxO6tDZfTlHPXrVJlM?p=preview

From side menu press About it prevents normally. Then press settings tab. It is trying to navigate to settings tab then shows the popup. Also settings tab cannot be loaded successfuly.

Comment: Please provide a complete and verifiable example, reproducing your issue. The code you provided is too general.

Comment: I've added a plunker demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the "settings" state (name "tabs.about", nested to "tabs"):

```
.state('tabs.about', {
  url: '/about',
  controller: 'AboutCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
});
```

then I've created a new controller ("mainCtrl") attached to `<body>` and moved here the `$stateChangeStart` event handler, so it can listen events without regard to the current state (previously it was in the Home controller):

```
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    var txt = '$stateChangeStart from: '+fromState.name+" to "+toState.name;
    console.log(txt);
    $rootScope.log = txt;
  })
```

Here is a plunker updated:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xcTMzPJdTVgVxV5jgpho